# Are there any conditions for using "would"?

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentences, is **on** appropriate or **for**? Can the first **about** be omitted? Is **would** correct?

> **On** (for) actual LiDAR sensors, the  lasers turn (**about**) or oscillate about an axis, as is demonstrated in Figure 1. As a result, the lasers that are not perpendicular to the axis (**would**) trace out a conical surface.

Comment: Why do you want to add _would_? There's nothing hypothetical about it: tracing out a conical surface is what lasers that are not perpendicular to the axis actually _do_.

Comment: In real-life LiDAR systems, the laser apparatus is physically *on* (*top of*) the sensor; so **on** is appropriate. A second *about* is not required (and could be read as redundant), because the sentence is (intended to be) parsed as "the lasers (turn [exclusive-]or oscillate) *about* an axis". Finally, the suggested *would* is **definitely not** appropriate, because the lasers, ***do**, in fact*, trace out a conical surface. That statement is *not* a counterfactual and introducing "*would*" would be an error.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet : I see. Thanks. I should not use **would**

Comment: In aggregate, your emendments suggest you *don't believe* the statement, and desire to frame it as a hypothetical. That choice is up to you, of course, but yes, the actual-vs-hypothetical perspective can and will dramatically change the language you use. That's the purpose of the [subjunctive mood in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), which ultimate may be the "conditions" you're asking about.

Comment: s/would/will/ and it will work.

Comment: @DanBron : Thanks for your explanation. As to the question of **on** versus **for**, what if the laser apparatus is not on top of the sensor? Is the phrase **the lasers for actual LiDAR sensors** correct or not?

Comment: They don't have to be "*on top of*" to be "*on*" (that was just me helping you internalize it). Your arms are *on* your body, despite not being *on top of* your body. Bark is *on* trees, even their very bottoms. "*On*" simply means "[somewhere] *on* the surface of", i.e. on the object's *outside*. If the lasers were instead *inside* the sensors, you'd say "*in*". In any case, **I would not say "*for*"**, for the same reason I would not say "my arms are *for* (="attached to"??) my body". If you're looking for a really non-committal preposition, try *of*: "The lasers *of* LiDAR sensors...".

Comment: PS: Though it ***doesn't apply** to the passage above*, which is all about geometries and physical relationships between parts, if the lasers were still in the warehouse and ***not yet attached*** to the LiDAR arrays, you could say "The lasers *for*...".

Answer (score -1):

In, on and for can be used almost interchangeably in this situation; readers will know what you mean!

If you want more detailed guidance, the usage I've seen is:

'In' for talking about designs and parts that are inside the device.
'For' for relative changes and motivations.
'On' for parts that are externally exposed.

Examples:

In the LMS-291 a single laser is used, parallel to the rotation axis of the spinning mirror.
In Stanford's design, six LIDARs were used.

For SICK's other product, the Ibeo Lux, four lasers are used instead of just one
For our latest robot, we decided to use a Velodyne HDL-64E
For eye safety, a class 1 infrared laser is the most common choice.
For practical systems, designers must consider what to do if the sensor is dazzled by direct sunlight.

On Stanley, Stanford's car, six LIDARs were used.
On newer LIDARs, ethernet is replacing RS232.
On the Velodyne pictured in Figure 2, two large lenses can be seen.

I would suggest using 'for' if making a comparison between actual LIDARs and something you've previously described. I would use 'in' if talking about internal components of actual LIDARs in general, or a specific design of LIDAR.